# LibreOffice Calc SECOND function returning wrong value - why?

Tags: function, libreoffice-calc, milliseconds, seconds

I have a table with a timestamp column (column `A`) that contains the timestamp *with **millisecond** resolution*.

**Example:**

[image]

I have separate columns for extracting different time 'components' (year, month, date, etc.), but the seconds column (`SS`) is giving the wrong value for the rows highlighted in red.

The formula for column `SS` is simply: `=SECOND([timestamp_column])`, for example in row 2, it is `=SECOND(A2)`

Why is it giving the wrong value for some rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It dawned on me upon looking closely that for all rows where the SECOND function returns the wrong answer, they are all the correct SECOND value +1. Looking at the milliseconds in the source column, I realized that they are all 500ms or more 'past the second'...therefore, the SECOND function must be ROUNDING.

The ONLY indication of this is nothing more than implied here:
[enter link description here](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Documentation/Calc_Functions/SECOND)

where is says:

[image]

That is the ***only*** use of the word "**ROUND**" on the entire page.

The formula to workaround this behaviour (*which is not a bug, it is just obtuse*) is:

`=SECOND(INT(A2*86400)/86400)`

which truncates the milliseconds off the source, or

`=TEXT(SECOND(INT(A2*86400)/86400),"00")`

if you want it formatted as a double digit.

The table now correctly extracts the '***CURRENT** SECOND*' of the timestamp in question, instead of the '***NEAREST** SECOND*':

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't even say it's obtuse. If you're asking for the seconds value of a timestamp, it's less of an error to give you the nearest second than the truncated one. For example, with `5.752`, `5` has an error percentage of ~13.1% while `6` has a roughly 4.3% error percentage.

Comment: Technically I agree - it's more correct. I just think there should be a clear statement explaining that 'the SECOND function ROUNDs to the nearest second, therefore if the millisecond value is 500 or more, SECOND will round up to the next second'. My reasoning is that in a large number of scenarios, it is natural to think of the time as 'the latest point we just passed'. If the time is 14:37:12 in the afternoon and I ask you "what is the time", you wouldn't say "tomorrow" or "3PM". You wouldn't normally even say "14:38", you would say "14:37"...I expect most people would say "14:37".

Answer (score 1):

You'll notice that all the "wrong" values of seconds actually come from a value with a fractional element that is greater than (or possibly greater than or equal to) `0.5`. For example, `2.577`, `5.752`, `8.754`, and so on.

Hence it's almost certainly rounding these numbers to the nearest integer.

From [some documentation found online](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Documentation/Calc_Functions/SECOND), it states the formula used is `SECOND = ROUND(MinuteFraction * 60)` so I would assume, if you need it truncated rather than rounded, you could use the formula:

```
=TRUNC(MinuteFraction * 60)
```

To calcucate `MinuteFraction` (as per that linked page):

```
DayFraction = DateTime – INT(DateTime)
HourFraction = (DayFraction * 24) - INT(DayFraction * 24)
MinuteFraction = (HourFraction * 60) - INT(HourFraction * 60)
```

Comment: Exactly - this is a rounding issue. I already knew the answer before I posted my question. I posted it for the benefit of others and my future self who may have forgotten...